# Custom cursor doesn't move

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, cursor

I'm trying to create a custom cursor for my website but it does not work well and I don't know what the problem is.

Here is the link to the code on Codepen

https://codepen.io/mahmoudkattan/pen/OJZXQow

```js
const cursorTag = document.querySelector("div.cursor");
const cursor = cursorTag.querySelector("div");

let currentX = 0;
let currentY = 0;
let aimX = 0;
let aimY = 0;
let speed = 0.3;

const animate = function () {
    currentX += (aimX - currentX) * speed;
    currentY += (aimY - currentY) * speed;

    cursor.style.left = currentX + "px";
    cursor.style.top = currentY + "px";

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

};

animate();

document.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    aimX = event.pageX;
    aimY = event.pageY;
});

console.log(aimX);
```

```css
div.cursor div {
    z-index: 9999999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid var(--white);
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor">
        <div></div>
     </div>
```

who can help with that?

Thanks

Comment: because you probably want mousemove and not over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change `mouseover` to `mousemove`

> ```
> document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
>     aimX = event.pageX;
>     aimY = event.pageY;
> });
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You want `mousemove` not `mouseover`